# C++/CLI Load variables from a .txt file using a special structure

Tags: file, c++-cli, structure, external, streamreader

Rather long question, and quite long story so I'll try to be as quick and precise as I can. I've written a program which allows the user to create questions for a quiz, and those options be exported into a .txt file with the below structure:

```
#
Level: 1
Ref: testRef
Question: test question
A: test A
B: test B
C: test C
D: test D
Ans: A
APerc: 100
BPerc: 0
CPerc: 0
DPerc: 0
Phone Answer: Right, I know this. The answer is 100% A. Good luck!
50/50: B
50/50 Percentage 1: 100
50/50 Percentage 2: 0
Force: True
!
```

Where

- # indicates the start of the question,
- Level is the part of the quiz this question is worth (the higher it is, the more difficult it is),
- A, B, C and D are the alternative answers,
- ans is the correct answers,
- APerc to 50/50 Percentage 2 are all info for assists to the user to answer the question if they use them,
- the value of force is whether this question should appear definitively or not, since their may be more than once question with the same level
- and ! indicates the end of a question.

Now, in terms of code what would be the easiest way to read the whole file and identify each of these individual questions with the aforementioned delimiters?

Would it be good to use something like `StreamReader`? I'd rather read the whole file,  then identify if any questions have been forced, then randomly pick 15 questions, either at the start of runtime or during the reveal of the next question, with different levels, possibly passing the value of the current level to the read function and then store all the question info in variables.

Comment: A text file is a pretty poor substitute for a dbase.  But sure, you'd use StreamReader and a bunch of code to Parse().  It gets easier when you use XML instead, you don't have to parse anymore.

Comment: I hate to say it, but use XML

Comment: Fair enough guys, I'll look into XML. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, do any of you have a basis of code in XML I could start off with?